# How can I keep redux state when I use nextjs To build server rendered JS web app with React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

When I refresh page my redux states get initial states , how can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because, `react` is a single page application, it will initialise its state when the user refresh the page. You have to set the redux store something like

```
const store = { //your initial store data };
const initStore = localStorage.getItem('store') || store;
```

For this you can write your own helper function to save data to the localStorage whenever you change your data or you can use something like `redux-storage` or `redux-localstorage`. So whenever you refresh the page, if there is data on the localStorage, it will be assigned to your app as a initial state.